# Calculate several traits with mutate in loop R

Tags: r

I try to use the function `mutate`in a loop to calcul the sum of many trees functional traits in same time.

Firstly, I try to calcul only the sum, var and skewness, kurtosis of the SLA (only one trait) by quadrats. For this, I did:

```
DF_qua_SLA <- DF_sp_25 %>% group_by(quadrats) %>%
  mutate(SLA_ab = (sum(SLA*abundance_pc))) %>% #Mean by abundance
  mutate(SLA_ba = (sum(SLA*ba_pc))) %>% #Mean by basal area
  mutate(SLA_var= (var(SLA)))%>% #Variance 
  mutate(SLA_sk= (skewness(SLA))) %>% #Skewness
  mutate(SLA_kwt= (kurtosis(SLA))) #Kurtosis
```

So far, everything works. So now I want to do the same thing for several functional traits with a loop:

```
for (a in c("LA","SLA","LC","LN","Sap_WSG")){
  DF_qua <- 
    DF_qua %>% group_by(quadrats) %>% 
    mutate((!! paste0(a,"_mean_ab")) := (sum(DF_sp_25[a]*abundance_pc)))%>% #Weighted average per abundance
    mutate((!! paste0(a,"_mean_ba")) := (sum(DF_sp_25[a]*ba_pc)))%>%#weighted average per basal area
    mutate((!! paste0(a,"_var")) := (var(DF_sp_25[a])))%>% #Variance 
    mutate((!! paste0(a,"_sk")) := (skewness(DF_sp_25a])))%>% #Skewness
    mutate((!! paste0(a,"_kwt")) := (kurtosis(DF_sp_25_[a]))) #Kurtosis
}
```

However, here I've a problem, the results between the first code (for SLA) and the second one (with many traits) aren't same:

[image]

So, the second code, the loop, have a problem but impossible to know which one.

**Any suggestions?** I can provide more info on the data if necessary.

Comment: Some input data would be helpful.  Personally, I'd transform to long, calculate the summaries and then (if necessary) back transform to wide.  Currently, your data frame is not tidy, because the column names contain information (the trait).  As a general rule of thumb, your life will be easier (no need to loop in this example, for instance, more robust, more compact code) if your data frame is [tidy](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html).

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Indeed, I agree with you, but this is not my code but a friend's one. Thanks to @RonakShah for your solution, it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `across` to avoid loops here.

```
library(dplyr)

cols <- c("LA","SLA","LC","LN","Sap_WSG")

DF_qua <- DF_sp_25 %>% 
           group_by(quadrats) %>%
           mutate(across(all_of(cols), list(ab  = ~sum(.*abundance_pc), 
                                            ba = ~sum(.*ba_pc), 
                                            var = ~var(.), 
                                            kwt= ~kurtosis(.))))
```